# Different request on same action with parameters

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

I want to search (say) "`accounts`" based on "name" or "status".

So I would like to have two actions :

- `GET /persons/?q=name==Jea*`
- `GET /persons/?q=status==locked`

How can I document that ?

I tried an [Action](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-action-section) with multiples transactions :

```
### GET /accounts{?q}

+ Request by name
    +Parameters
        +q (required, FIQLQuery)
        **Only name is supported**

+ Request by status
    +Parameters
        +q (required, FIQLQuery)
        **Only status is supported**
```

But Apiary editor complains because :

1. I must provide a message-body for my GET requests:

   > Message-body asset is expected to be a pre-formatted code block, every of its line indented by exactly 8 spaces or 2 tabs.
2. The `+ Parameters` block is not recognized :

   > Ignoring unrecognized block

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i can make solution that works for me.

Try this API Blueprint:

```
FORMAT: 1A

# requestByname

## Accounts [/accounts/?{q,type}]

### GET

+ Parameters
    + q (required, FIQLQuery)
    + type (string, `name` or `status`)

+ Request Name (application/json)

+ Response 200

        {"name": "test"}

+ Request Status (application/json)

+ Response 200

        {"status": 200}
```

Comment: Of course, there is a lot of alternatives solutions. But I don't want to use an extra parameter.